# Try to recover posts with a RSS Feed from a blog to my Gatsby site, someone know what is the good plugin and how to pars query?

Tags: rss, gatsby, rss-reader, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-plugin-feed

New in GatsbyJS, I need Help to check a RSS Feed and I'm lost !

I want to check the rss feed of another blog to my gatsby site, I want to get back the posts of this blog to my gatsby site.

Someone can tell me if I need to install:
"gatsby source rss feed" (I think), "gatsby source rss" or "gatsby rss feed" (I think it's not it, dit for push his gatsby posts to another blog, I need the reverse) ?

If someone can also show me how to declare the query of rss? And In witch folder?

My gatsby-config.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const config = require("./data/siteConfig")

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: ``,
    author: config.authorName,
    description: config.siteDescription,
    siteUrl: config.siteUrl,
    ...config,
  },
  pathPrefix: `/froggit.fr`,
  plugins: [
  
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "pages",
        path: "content/pages",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "posts",
        path: "content/posts",
        //path: "src/page/blog",
      },
    },
  
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: "content/images",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
      options: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `pages`),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/settings/pages`,
      },
   },  
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
        defaultLayouts: {
          
          default: require.resolve("./src/templates/page.js"),
    
          
        },
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false,
              withWebp: true,
            },
          },
          { resolve: "gatsby-remark-prismjs" },
          { resolve: "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe" },
          { resolve: "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files" },
          { resolve: "gatsby-remark-smartypants" },
          { resolve: "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers" },
        ],
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [`gatsby-remark-images`],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: config.googleAnalyticsId,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-rss-feed`,
      options: {
        url: `https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/rss.xml`,
        name: `GatsbyBlog`,
        
        parserOption: {
          customFields: {
            item: ['itunes:duration']
          }
        }
      }
    },


{ 
  resolve: '@uptimeventures/gatsby-source-rss',
  options: {
    feeds: ['https://www.uptime.ventures/blog/rss.xml'],
  },
},

                {
                        resolve: 'gatsby-source-rss',
                        options: {
                                rssURL: 'https://lydra.fr/tag/froggit/feed/rss.xml'
                        }
                },
 
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: {
        setup: (options) => ({
          ...options,
          custom_namespaces: {
            yournamespace: "https://lydra.fr/tag/froggit/feed/",
          },
        }),
        feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({
              query: { allMarkdownRemark },
            }) => {
              return allMarkdownRemark.edges.map((edge) => {
                return Object.assign(
                  {},
                  edge.node.frontmatter,
                  {
                    
                    custom_elements: [
                      //{ "content:encoded": edge.node.html },
                      { "yournamespace:yourcustomfield": edge.node.fields.someField },
                    ],
                  }
                );
              });
            },
          },
        ],
        
      },
    },


{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-rss',
  options: {
    rssURL: 'https://blog.jordanrhea.com/rss.xml',
    customFields: {
      item: ['tags'],
    },
  },
},
*/

{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
  options: {
    query: `
      {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            siteUrl
            site_url: siteUrl
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    feeds: [
      {
        serialize: ({ query: { site, allMarkdownRemark } }) => {
          return allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(edge => {
            return Object.assign({}, edge.node.frontmatter, {
              description: edge.node.excerpt,
              date: edge.node.frontmatter.date,
              url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
              guid: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
              custom_elements: [{ "content:encoded": edge.node.html }],
            })
          })
        },
        query: `
          {
            allMarkdownRemark(
              sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
            ) {
              edges {
                node {
                  excerpt
                  html
                  fields { slug }
                  frontmatter {
                    title
                    date
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        output: "/rss.xml",
        title: "Your Site's RSS Feed",
      },
    ],
  },
},

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-podcast-rss-feed`,
      options: {
        feedURL: `https://lydra.fr/ea-2-le-podcasteur-erwan/rss`,
        id: 'guid',
      },
  },
  

  {
    resolve: `@arshad/gatsby-theme-podcast-core`,
    options: {
      feedUrl: `https://blog.jordanrhea.com/rss.xml`,
      podcast: {
        name: `Name of Podcast`,
        description: `Eligendi nisi nobis nisi voluptate. Corporis deserunt provident hic numquam. Veritatis vero necessitatibus adipisci cumque voluptate rerum at.`,
        image: `content/images/podcast.jpg`,
        social: [
          {
            name: `Apple Podcast`,
            url: `https://itunes.apple.com`,
          },
          {
            name: `Google Podcast`,
            url: `https://podcasts.google.com`,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },

  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-youtube`,
    options: {
      channelId: '<<Youtube channelID eg. UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA >>',
      apiKey: '<< Add your Youtube api key here>>',
      maxVideos: 50 // Defaults to 50
    },
  },

    
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: config.siteTitle,
        short_name: config.siteTitle,
        start_url: config.pathPrefix,
        background_color: config.background_color,
        theme_color: config.theme_color,
        display: config.display,
        icon: "content/images/logo_froggit.png",
      },
    },
   
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-compile-es6-packages",
      options: {
        modules: ["gatsby-starter-morning-dew"],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

In my file: **gatsby-node.js**? I have copied some code for create my rss feed but I don't understand a lot of things...

```
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")

const { load, createFeed } = require('./internals')
async function sourceNodes({ boundActionCreators }, options = {}) {
  const { createNode } = boundActionCreators
  const { feeds = [] } = options

  for (const f of feeds) {
    const { rss } = await load(f)

    if (rss && rss.channel) {
      const sources = (Array.isArray(rss.channel)
        ? rss.channel : [rss.channel]
      )

      sources.forEach(f => createFeed(f, createNode))
    }
  }

  return Promise.resolve()
}

module.exports = {
  sourceNodes,
}


exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const BlogPostTemplate = require.resolve("./src/templates/blog-post.js")
  const BlogPostShareImage = require.resolve(
    "./src/templates/blog-post-share-image.js"
  )
  const PageTemplate = require.resolve("./src/templates/page.js")
  const PostsBytagTemplate = require.resolve("./src/templates/tags.js")
  const ListPostsTemplate = require.resolve(
    "./src/templates/list.js"
  )

  const allMarkdownQuery = await graphql(`
  {
    allMarkdown: allMdx(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { published: { ne: false } } }
      limit: 1000
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          fileAbsolutePath
          frontmatter {
            title
            slug
            tags
            language
            cover {
              publicURL
            }
            unlisted
          }
          timeToRead
          excerpt
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)

  if (allMarkdownQuery.errors) {
    reporter.panic(allMarkdownQuery.errors)
  }

  const postPerPageQuery = await graphql(`
    {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          postsPerPage
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const markdownFiles = allMarkdownQuery.data.allMarkdown.edges

  const posts = markdownFiles.filter(item =>
    item.node.fileAbsolutePath.includes("/content/posts/")
  )

 
  actions.createPage({
    path: '/blog',
    component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/list.js`),
    context: {},
  })


  
  const postsPerPage = postPerPageQuery.data.site.siteMetadata.postsPerPage
  const nbPages = Math.ceil(listedPosts.length / postsPerPage)

  Array.from({ length: nbPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/` : `/pages/${i + 1}`,
      component: ListPostsTemplate,
      context: {
        limit: postsPerPage,
        skip: i * postsPerPage,
        currentPage: i + 1,
        nbPages: nbPages,
      },
    })

  posts.forEach((post, index, posts) => {
    const previous = index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node
    const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node

    createPage({
      path: post.node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: BlogPostTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: post.node.frontmatter.slug,
        previous,
        next,
      },
    })

    if (process.env.gatsby_executing_command.includes("develop")) {
      createPage({
        path: `${post.node.frontmatter.slug}/image_share`,
        component: BlogPostShareImage,
        context: {
          slug: post.node.frontmatter.slug,
          width: 440,
          height: 220,
        },
      })
    }
  })

  markdownFiles
    .filter(item => item.node.fileAbsolutePath.includes("/content/pages/"))
    .forEach(page => {
      createPage({
        path: page.node.frontmatter.slug,
        component: PageTemplate,
        context: {
          slug: page.node.frontmatter.slug,
        },
      })
    })


  markdownFiles
    .filter(item => item.node.frontmatter.tags !== null)
    .reduce(
      (acc, cur) => [...new Set([...acc, ...cur.node.frontmatter.tags])],
      []
    )
    .forEach(uniqTag => {
      createPage({
        path: `tags/${uniqTag}`,
        component: PostsBytagTemplate,
        context: {
          tag: uniqTag,
        },
      })
    })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}


const parser = require('rss-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const createContentDigest = obj => crypto.createHash('md5').update(JSON.stringify(obj)).digest('hex');

function promisifiedParseURL(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    parser.parseURL(url, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data.feed);
    });
  });
}

const createChildren = (entries, parentId, createNode) => {
  const childIds = [];
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    childIds.push(entry.link);
    const node = Object.assign({}, entry, {
      id: entry.link,
      title: entry.title,
      link: entry.link,
      description: entry.description,
      parent: parentId,
      children: []
    });
    node.internal = {
      type: 'rssFeedItem',
      contentDigest: createContentDigest(node)
    };
    createNode(node);
  });
  return childIds;
};

async function sourceNodes({ boundActionCreators }, { rssURL }) {
  const { createNode } = boundActionCreators;
  const data = await promisifiedParseURL(rssURL);
  if (!data) {
    return;
  }
  const { title, description, link, entries } = data;
  const childrenIds = createChildren(entries, link, createNode);
  const feedStory = {
    id: link,
    title,
    description,
    link,
    parent: null,
    children: childrenIds
  };

  feedStory.internal = { type: 'rssFeed', contentDigest: createContentDigest(feedStory) };

  createNode(feedStory);
}

exports.sourceNodes = sourceNodes;
```

Or again in a folder of my template?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin [gatsby-plugin-parse-rss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-parse-rss) will parse information from RSS feed page and automatically create the queries.

Add the plugin in your `gatsby-config.js`

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-parse-rss",
    options: {
      rss: [
        {
          urlToFetch:
            "https://lydra.fr/tag/froggit/feed/rss.xml",
          selectors: ["media:title"],
          name: "lydraRSS",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

Use gatsby's `useStaticQuery` to retrieve data

```
{
  allLydraRss {
    nodes {
      media_title
    }
  }
}
```